# Very odd SSH known_hosts verification failure with certificates

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I recently upgraded one of my machines to latest Ubuntu 22.04, and now I am experiencing a very strange SSH server verification issue. Here is a short explanation of the situation.

I am using SSH certificate-based authentication, both for servers and clients. The client authentication is working correctly (servers have `TrustedUserCAKeys` for client auth), but server verification is not. I have `@cert-authority *.example.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHN...` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` (which does get read correctly, confirmed with strace) but for some reason it is not being properly used. Or actually it would likely be used, except that the server is not sending its certificate to the client. This only happens with a recent version (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1) of client, but works correctly with an older version (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10). Below are a couple of extracts from SSH debug logs both for new and old client.

New client debug log:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to my.example.com:22 as 'myuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+JwFUaD...
```

Old client debug log:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to my.example.com:22 as 'myuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host certificate: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com SHA256:+JwFUaD..., serial 10356 ID "my.example.com server certificate" CA ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:KlV0xkm... valid from 2023-05-30T12:18:00 to 2023-06-06T12:19:31
debug1: Host 'my.example.com' is known and matches the ECDSA-CERT host certificate.
debug1: Found CA key in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:1
```

As can be seen, the server only sends a `Server host key` instead of the expected `Server host certificate`. The only difference I can see is that the new client uses kex algo `curve25519-sha256` and the old (functional) one uses `curve25519-sha256@libssh.org`. But from what I gather, these are supposed to be the same, just with a new name.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be going on here? The signing CAs for both servers and clients are ecdsa keys, if that makes any difference.